# A polynomial inequality in three variables

Tags: inequality

I have a polynomial $P(A,B,C)$ where $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A>0,B>0$. 
$$P(A,B,C)=C^2+A^2-2CA+4AB-2B+C-A$$

When will

1. $P(A,B,C)>0$
2. $P(A,B,C)=0$
3. $P(A,B,C)<0$

I have tried factorizing in various ways but none of them is very helpful. Any ideas here?

My attempt:

$P(A,B,C)=(C-A)^2+(C-A)+2B(2A-1)=(C-A)(C-A+1)+2B(2A-1)$

which leads to nowhere

Comment: $P(A,B,C) = (C-A+\frac12)^2 + (B+A-\frac12)^2 - (B-A+\frac12)^2 - \frac14$.
From coordinate system $(u,v,w) = (C-A+\frac12,B+A-\frac12,B-A+\frac12)$, you can see $P = 0$ is a single sheet hyperbola.

Comment: @achillehui nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=C-A$, then $P(A,B,C)=x^2+x+2B(2A-1) \equiv f(x)$.

$$\Delta=1^2-4(2B)(2A-1)=1-8B(2A-1)$$

- $\Delta < 0 \implies f(x)>0$,

$$1<8B(2A-1) \implies 2A-1> \frac{1}{8B} \implies A> \frac{8B+1}{16B}$$

- $\Delta \ge 0 \land f(x) < 0$,
  $$\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-8B(2A-1)}}{2} < C-A < \frac{-1+\sqrt{1-8B(2A-1)}}{2}$$ where $0<A \le \dfrac{8B+1}{16B}$.
- $\Delta \ge 0 \land f(x) = 0$,
  $$C-A=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-8B(2A-1)}}{2}$$  where $0<A \le \dfrac{8B+1}{16B}$.
- $\Delta \ge 0 \land f(x) > 0$,
  $$\left| C-A+\frac{1}{2} \right|> \frac{\sqrt{1-8B(2A-1)}}{2}$$ where $0<A \le \dfrac{8B+1}{16B}$.

Comment: There is another source of $f(x)>0$ when $\Delta \geq 0$... Right?

Comment: Included in the updated answer.

Comment: @ Ng Chung Tak Please check the following typo as well: 2nd case upper bound should have the square-root of the determinant with plus sign.